# What court was Anne Sacoolas tried by?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales

I’m guessing either Magistrates or crown court. I know it was the central criminal court which I suppose is a location of the crown court, but i don’t really know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sentencing remarks](https://www.judiciary.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/R-v-Sacoolas-sentencing-081222.pdf) note the proceedings occurred in the [*Central Criminal Court*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Bailey), short for Central Criminal Court of England and Wales, also known as *Old Bailey*. This is a location of the Crown Court.